# error call to undefined function odbc_connect()

Tags: php, conexión

Básicamente me pidieron una página web a lo cual accedí, el único detalle es que el inventario debe cargarse automáticamente a la página web y A2 de softway utiliza Dbisam, descargue el driver odbc e intente hacer la conexión con php, pero aún así no funciona, no consigo nada del tema en Google, por lo cual procedí a realizar mi primera pregunta, agradezco cualquier información.

Este fue el código que probé:

```
<?php
$db = odbc_connect("DRIVER={DBISAM 4 ODBC Driver};ConnectionType=Local;CatalogName=C:/...../Data;","a2server","");
$res = odbc_exec($db," CONSULTA SELECT ");
?>
```

Pero me da un error:

> error call to undefined function odbc_connect()

Y tengo los drivers descargados no entiendo.

Comment: $db = odbc_connect("DRIVER={DBISAM 4 ODBC Driver};ConnectionType=Local;CatalogName=C:/...../Data;","a2server",""); $res = odbc_exec($db," CONSULTA SELECT "); ese es el código que utilice

Comment: Tal vez alguna de estas soluciones podría funcionarte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321203/call-to-undefined-function-odbc-connect-php-7

Comment: *descargue el driver odbc* ... Pero, ¿descargaste el controlador correcto, acorde con la versión de base de datos, sistema operativo, PHP, etc? ¿está habilitado el controlador? Si te dice que no  encuentra la función es porque no descargaste el controlador correcto o porque no está habilitado. Indica qué pasos has dado para la instalación/habilitación y qué comprobaciones has hecho en php.ini, en la consola, con phpinfo, etc.

Comment: Siendo honestos nunca he hecho una conexión con dbisam, y estoy perdido, sin embargo lo habilité en php.ini, y cuando abro el archivo php, se queda cargando y nunca termina de cargar, no muestra error, ni tampoco muestra la información, realmente no sé que sucede y necesito lograr la conexión antes del lunes :/

Answer (score 0):

El error se debía a xampp, para conectarse se necesita utilizar la versión x84, lo descubrí gracias a un blog, también influye la versión, debe ser la 3.2.2.